# Check duplicates before copying rows from one datagrid to another datagrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Actually I am copying rows from one `datagrid` to another on DataGridView Double Click Event, and it's going well. The code is here:

```
 //Void App
 void AddProducts(int ProdID, string Name, string ProductCode, int RetailPrice, int SalePrice, string BrandName, string Category, int QTY)
    {
        string[] row = { Convert.ToUInt32(ProdID).ToString(), Name, ProductCode, 
         Convert.ToInt32(RetailPrice).ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(SalePrice).ToString(), BrandName, Category, Convert.ToInt32(QTY).ToString()};

        dgViewProductsToSell.Rows.Add(row);
    }

 //Code

 private void dgViewProducts_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string Name1 = this.dgViewProducts.CurrentRow.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
        int ProdID = Convert.ToInt32(dgViewProducts.CurrentRow.Cells["ProdID"].Value);
        string Name = dgViewProducts.CurrentRow.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
        string ProductCode = dgViewProducts.CurrentRow.Cells["ProductCode"].Value.ToString();
        int RetailPrice = Convert.ToInt32(dgViewProducts.CurrentRow.Cells["RetailPrice"].Value);
        int SalePrice = Convert.ToInt32(dgViewProducts.CurrentRow.Cells["SalePrice"].Value);
        string BrandName = dgViewProducts.CurrentRow.Cells["BrandName"].Value.ToString();
        string Category = dgViewProducts.CurrentRow.Cells["Category"].Value.ToString();
        int QTY = Convert.ToInt32(dgViewProducts.CurrentRow.Cells["QTY"].Value);

        AddProducts(Convert.ToInt32(ProdID), Name, ProductCode, Convert.ToInt32(RetailPrice), Convert.ToInt32(SalePrice), BrandName, Category, Convert.ToInt32(QTY));
 }
```

How I can check duplicate entries before copying the rows? So the 2nd `datagridview` could avoid duplicate entries.

Comment: What defines a duplicate?

Comment: Datagridviews shouldnt be used to hold data directly. It is easier to work with your data stored in a datatable and bind the datagridview to the table. In this context you can establish a primary key on the destination datatable and every tine the user clicks to transfer a row, perform a lookup in the destination table for that row. If the row already exists, don't transfer it. When you give a datatable a primary key you can use the dedicated Find method. Using strongly typed datatables  will also make your life easier

Comment: means if user double click to the datagridview1's row then it should check that the same row is already inserted in the 2nd datagridview OR not. and it will check on the specific column like dgview1.columns["Name"].Value will check against dgview2.columns["Name"].Value

Comment: If it is possible for you for now to give only a few moments to show me an example code for it, I will really very appreciate it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to start off with this scrappy test app:

[image]

Don't worry that it's a screenshot of code - that's just for information purposes of how it came to be that I generated a datagridview with some data in it. This is how do "do it properly" - you keep your data in a DataTable and you use a grid to show it

The next step: we are going to make a strongly typed dataset, datatable, set its primary key, put it on the form along with a datagridview it is bound to, and we are going to fill it uniquely by double clicking the existing grid. I modeled the existing grid more like you have done. In reality I would make BOTH these grids be based on a strongly typed data table, but I wanted to show you you didn't have to, and my advice for making a strongly typed datatable can fit in with your existing idea of stuffing data into a datagridview directly, until you're ready to change over

Add a new DataSet type item to your project. Right click the project, Add.. New Item:

[image]

Give it a nice name. Nothing worse than code full of Form1, DataSet1, GridView3, Button27

---

When it's added, double click it to open the design surface. Right click the surface and add a new datatable:

[image]

---

Give it a nice name, right click it repeatedly and add columns for all you want, Name, Code, Price etc:

[image]

---

Don't forget to give them a datatype too, so not everything is a string!

[image]

---

You said you want to be unique by name so.. Click in the grey bit next to Name so the row goes all blue, then right click and choose Set primary key

[image]

---

Save it all, close the dataset designer, go to the forms designer, click the VIEW menu, go to OTHER WINDOWS >> DATASOURCES. You can also  press `Shift+Alt+D`

Open the DATA SOURCES panel, find the grid node of your datatable (whatever you called it) and drag it onto the form

[image]

---

A datagridview, connected to your custom datatable has appeared, together with some new things at the bottom. You can delete the bindingnavigator:

[image]

(and rename the dataset instance so it has a nicer name than xxxxDataSet1)

---

That's all the setup we need for now to set up the receiver datatable, and grid. Let's edit the event handler for the mouse double click. I jiggled things around a bit and added another feature as a demonstration, that if the row IS there we can update it, otherwise we add it:

```
    private void _dataGridViewSrc_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        //my source datagrid is bound to a datatable. I use this to retrieve the current row related
        //to the row in the grid that was double clicked
        DataRow sourceRow = (_dataGridViewSrc.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView)?.Row;

        if(sourceRow == null)
            return;

        //because we made Name the primary key, the strongly typed datatable has a FindByName method
        //we pass it the string Name from the source datatable row (a grid row cell value in your case)
        NiceNameDataSet.UniqueProductsRow destRow = _niceNameDataSet.UniqueProducts.FindByName((string)sourceRow["Name"]);

        //FindByName returns NULL if the row wasn't found
        if(destRow == null)
        {
            //the row isn't there, so add it, using the data from the source row
            _niceNameDataSet.UniqueProducts.AddUniqueProductsRow(
                (string)sourceRow["Name"],
                (string)sourceRow["Code"],
                (double)sourceRow["Price"]
            );
        } else
        {
            //the row IS there, how about we update the fields using the row that was just clicked?
            //this demonstrated how much nicer it is to work with a strongly typed dataset/datatable
            //because all the columns have proper Properties, like row.Code, with proeprt datatypes
            //like string and double, rather than having to be referred to with a string name like 
            //row["Code"] and having to be cast from object to string, double all the time: messy 
            //and error prone
            destRow.Code = (string)sourceRow["Code"];
            destRow.Price = (double)sourceRow["Price"];

        }

    }
```

I changed the prices and codes a bit to demo this other featuer. Now you can double click either bread row as much as you like and you only get one row in the destination grid, and it changes its values back and forth:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail :) . By the way I have solved my question myself and I will be adding the right way in the end of question that I've found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object which represents each row with properties for each column. For this object you can create an `public bool Equals(object obj)` method. 
With the object you can compare already read objects with newly read objects. Either manually or by using something `Contains` or similar methods which are part of `List<>` and `Dictionary<>` classes.

It all depends on how much data you have and which line you consider to be equal to another line. Is it equal / a collision if the product ID is a duplicate or do all properties   also have to match

Comment: I just need to check duplicates on just a specific column and the bothe datagridview has the same column. I am not familiar with Lists<> type of objects as I am new in c# coding but I am learning day by day. If you can please give me an example code, I will be thankful.

Comment: You can look up the List at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Each row should have a **primary key**, usually an ID. I am assuming this is the case for you.

Second assumption: both `datagridview` controls are bound to datatables/datasets or binding sources.

So, when the user selects a row in the grid, retrieve the **underlying datarow**. This can be done using the [`databounditem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRow_DataBoundItem) function. Then you can fetch the ID or primary key.

Then compare the two datatables. This is more efficient and safer than accessing UI controls. There are different ways to check that a record already exists in a datatable, for example the [`select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.8) function. Another option is using LINQ.

Do not try to update the second datagridview directly, instead you add a record to its underlying datatable, and you let the datagridview update itself.

Your code seems to be unsafe. What happens if the user double-clicks on the edges of the grid ? The current row could be -1. You need to add a check.

You should also test what happens if the user sorts the columns in the datagrid or drag the columns to change the display order.

To sum up I strongly advise to use datatables, even if you are not reading from or saving to database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove duplicate entries before copying the datagridview.

Code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Id");
            table.Columns.Add("Age");
            table.Rows.Add("test1",1001,22);
            table.Rows.Add("test1", 1001, 22);
            table.Rows.Add("test2", 1002, 23);
            table.Rows.Add("test3", 1003, 24);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
            dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I correctly understand your question but maybe this will help
before adding into my gridview I already checked the possibility of duplicate

```
//Validate duplicate data b4 adding to gridview
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Product already on the list, if you wish to  add this product click the product name and edit the quantity", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox1.Focus();
        return;
    } else { }
}
```

then pass the datagridview1(form1) to datagridview2(form2)

```
List<PurChaseRcpT> cdgv = new List<PurChaseRcpT>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow Item in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    cdgv.Add(new PurChaseRcpT {
        Particular = Item.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
        Qty = Item.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
        UM = Item.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
        Price = Item.Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
        Total = Item.Cells[5].Value.ToString()
    });
}

FrM_SubChange ChangeFrm = new FrM_SubChange();
ChangeFrm.dataGridViewPassed = this.dataGridView2;
ChangeFrm.TempVal = cdgv;    
ChangeFrm.Show();
```

hope it help..